# JSON.parse causes Chrome tab to crash ("Aw, Snap") despite use of try/catch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome

I'm loading some JSON data from an AJAX query:

```
       $.ajax({'url': url, type: params.method, 'data': data, timeout: this.settings.timeout, success: function(d,a,x){
                console.log('request Complete',params.endpoint,params.params);
                var json = null;
                try {
                    json = JSON.parse(d);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }
                console.log('json');

                // omitted for brevity...
            }
        });
```

I'm seeing occasional "Aw, Snap" crashes in chrome where the last console.log is the "request Complete" (the error or 2nd log never get shown).

I suppose that it's important to note that the data may be large (sometimes as big as ~15Mb), which is why I'm not printing out `d` on every request and looking for malformed JSON (yet... I may result to that). FWIW, I've also tried `$.parseJSON` instead of `JSON.parse`

Research I've done into the "Aw, Snap" error is vague, at best. My best guess atm is that this is an OOM. Unfortunately, there's not much I can do to decrease the footprint of the result-set.

Is there any way I could, at the least, gracefully fail?

Comment: OOM in `JSON.parse` shouldn't cause a crash, at least.

Comment: *"...the data may be large (sometimes as big as ~15Mb)"* Likely your problem. A `try/catch` won't help you there.

Comment: ...see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833480/have-i-reached-the-limits-of-the-size-of-objects-javascript-in-my-browser-can-ha)

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you tell jQuery the response data is JSON via the `dataType` property? Doing so should cause jQuery to pre parse and just give you the data. If you're right about what is going on, it seems this might cause a crash too. jQuery does some sanity checks before parsing, though.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: params.method,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: this.settings.timeout,
    success: function (d, a, x){
        // `d` should already be parsed into an object or array, and ready to use
    }
});
```

If that doesn't help, please post your actual JSON response for us to take a look at.

Comment: I hadn't considered that the jQuery parsing might perform extra checks; I'll try this and see if the issue is resolved (might take some time to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

"@the system" nailed it. 15MB of info coming back is too much for your browser to handle. I tripped upon this trying to see why my 64 Byte encoded image string is crashing the chrome tab, and it's only 200-500KB.

**To 'gracefully fail'**, it seems you will need to have server side logic in place to prevent this from happening; perhaps limit the size of the JSON string. Only have X characters of length in the initial JSON string and add a property for 'isFinishedSending: false' or 'leftOff: [index/some marker]' so you can timeout for a bit and hit your server again with the the place you left off.

Comment: This looks like it might be better suited to be a comment rather than posted as an answer.

Comment: it should... i dont have the rep to comment... silly silly system. kind of caters to having me create issues that aren't really issues just to get someone to answer