# Is there any way for me to work with this 100,000 item new-line separated string of words?

Tags: javascript

I've got a 100,000+ long list of English words in plain text. I want to use `split()` to convert the list into an array, which I can then convert to an associative array, giving each list item a key equal to its own name, so I can very efficiently check whether or not a string is an English word.

Here's the problem:

The list is new-line separated.

```
aa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
```

This means that `var list = ' <copy/paste list> '` isn't going to work, because JavaScript quotes don't work multi-line.

**Is there any way for me to work with this 100,000 item new-line separated string?**

Comment: Are you working in the browser, in nodejs, or some other environment? My initial thought is just to read it in from a file rather than as a string literal, but the details of how to do that vary depending on the environment you're in.

Comment: Generate the correct array literal from the start. You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4833480/139010

Comment: @ChrisTavares I can use either.

Comment: Why do you think splitting into an array, then converting to an object is more efficient than say [*String.prototype.indexOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.7) on the original string?

Comment: Look at what other people have done with scrabble dictionaries. http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/

Answer (score 5):

replace the newlines with commas in any texteditor before copying to your js file

Answer (score 3):

One workaround would be to use paste the list into notepad++. Then select all and Edit>Line Operations>Join lines.

This removes new lines and replaces them with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this client side, you can use jQuery's `get` function to get the words from a text file and do the processing there:

```
jQuery.get('wordlist.txt', function(results){
    //Do your processing on results here
});
```

If you're doing this in Node.js, follow the guide [here](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs) to see how to read a file into memory.

Comment: Also a great solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can use notepad++ or any semi-advanced text editor.

1. Go to notepad++ and push *Ctrl+H* to bring up the Replace dialog.
2. Towards the bottom, select the "Extended" Search Mode
3. You want to find "\r\n" and replace it with ", "

This will remove the newlines and replace it with commas

Comment: You would have to add the missing quotes too.

Answer (score 3):

***[`jsfiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/2wLC3/)***

Addressing this purely from having a string and trying to work with it in JavaScript through copy paste. Specifically the issues regarding, "*This means that var list = '  ' isn't going to work, because JavaScript quotes don't work multi-line.*", and "*Is there any way for me to work with this 100,000 item new-line separated string?*".

You can treat the string like a string in a comment in JavaScript . Although counter-intuitive, this is an interesting approach. Here is the main function

```
function convertComment(c) {
 return c.toString().
  replace(/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '').
  replace(/\*\/[^\/]+$/, '');
}
```

It can be used in your situation as follows:

```
var s = convertComment(function() {
 /*

 aa
 aah
 aahed
 aahing
 aahs
 aal
 aalii
 aaliis
 aals

 */
});
```

At which point you may do whatever you like with s. The demo simply places it into a div for displaying.

---

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Qfnuf/)***

Further, here is an example of taking the list of words, getting them into an array, and then referencing a single word in the array.

```
//previously shown code
var all = s.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
var rand = parseInt(Math.random() * all.length);

document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = "Random index #"+rand+": "+all[rand];
```

Answer (score 2):

For variety, another solution is to put the unaltered content into

1. A data attribute - HTML attributes can contain newlines
2. *or* a "non-script" script - eg. `<SCRIPT TYPE="text/x-wordlist">`
3. *or* an HTML comment node
4. *or* another hidden element that allows content

Then the content could be read and split/parsed. Since this would be done outside of JavaScript's string literal parsing it doesn't have the issue regarding embedded newlines.

Answer (score 2):

If the words are in a separate file, you can load them directly into the page and go from there. I've used a script element with a MIME type that should mean browsers ignore the content (provided it's in the head):

```
<script type="text/plain" id="wordlist">
aa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
</script>

<script>

var words = (function() {
  var words = '\n' + document.getElementById('wordlist').textContent + '\n';
  return {
    checkWord: function (word) {
      return words.indexOf('\n' + word + '\n') != -1;
    }
  }
}());

console.log(words.checkWord('aaliis')); // true
console.log(words.checkWord('ahh'));    // false

</script>
```

The result is an object with one method, *checkWord*, that has access to the word list in a closure. You could add more methods like *addWord* or *addVariant*, whatever.

Note that *textContent* may not be supported in all browsers, you may need to feature detect and use *innerText* or an alternative for some.