# JavaScript object size too huge for browser to handle (Aw, Snap!)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, memory-management

My application needs a JSON object for some processing on client side. From the server side I'm receiving 2 array's each of 500+ MB (more than 1GB of data - worst case scenario). Since the processing is done on client side I do need entire data set. But the problem is the browser is not able to handle this large data. (And for obvious reason we are soon going to move the processing on server side for next phase, but currently it is handled on client side). Is there any way to handle this situation, maybe to efficiently handle the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this much of data to client side will take lot of time to download before moving for processing. You may optimize processing but cannot optimize downloading. You may split the data into batches or the only solution is the one you have mentioned i.e. moving the processing on server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did find this link a bit helpful would need a try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833480/have-i-reached-the-limits-of-the-size-of-objects-javascript-in-my-browser-can-ha