# Getting Invalid JSON error when string returned back to JSONP Jquery Call

Tags: json, c#-2.0, jsonp

I am having below JSONP full string which is return back to clientside from my aspx page.

```
"processjsonp({\"result\": [\"CreateCityKeys\", \"Keyword -Spokane already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Anchorage already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Fairbanks already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Bellingham already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Juneau already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Boise already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Victoria already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Kelowna already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Eugene already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Medford already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Tucson already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Walla Walla already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Wenatchee already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Pasco already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Pullman already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Redmond already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Yakima already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Ketchikan already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Kauai Island already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Kona already exists in City\r\nKeyword -Kahului already exists in City\r\n\"]})"
```

I know the error must be beacuse of \r\n in between, please suggest to get rid of this.

Thanks

M.S.

EDIT: Error - JSONP parser error

Comment: It just a parsor error when it comes back to client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON syntax is not correct, You may replace \" with just " and chech the parser string limitation [here talks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold) about this

Comment: Ok then how can I show all above text in new line as this string is made from using StringBuilder.AppendLine, pleas suggest

Comment: I gues you may split the longest string and then use foreach in order to print it

Comment: Sorry, check this example:
    {"result": [
        "CreateCityKeys",
        "0xxxxxx" , "1xxxx", ... "Nxxxx"
    ]}
And then just do something like foerach (item : jsonX.result) { print item
}

Answer (score 0):

**example server response:**

```
json = {"result": ["CreateCityKeys", "Keyword -Spokane already exists in City", "Keyword -Anchorage already exists in City", "Keyword -Fairbanks already exists in City", "Keyword -Bellingham already exists in City", "Keyword -Juneau already exists in City", "Keyword -Boise already exists in City", "Keyword -Victoria already exists in City", "Keyword -Kelowna already exists in City", "Keyword -Eugene already exists in City", "Keyword -Medford already exists in City", "Keyword -Tucson already exists in City", "Keyword -Walla Walla already exists in City", "Keyword -Wenatchee already exists in City", "Keyword -Pasco already exists in City", "Keyword -Pullman already exists in City", "Keyword -Redmond already exists in City", "Keyword -Yakima already exists in City", "Keyword -Ketchikan already exists in City", "Keyword -Kauai Island already exists in City", "Keyword -Kona already exists in City", "Keyword -Kahului already exists in City",]}
```

**demo with jquery:**

```
x = jQuery.parseJSON( json )
$.each(x.result, function(i, item){
    document.write('<p>' + item + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: Hwy Toloo, I don't want to print all the string only the result[1] as I don't want to print "CreateCityKeys", and also it will not be easier to make above format string as it is created dynamically, please suggest another way

Comment: tell us what you really want..., is is just 2nd item (means result[1]) just replace $each.... with document.write(x.result[1]); is that ok?