# JSON data limit?

Tags: ios, json, nsdata

** I have some times 168416 bytes received in one single parse.

```
-(void)getConnector        // PESQUISA
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *getJson = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlEntra]]];

    [getJson setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [getJson addValue:@"getValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];

    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:getJson delegate:self];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

---

Is there any limit for how much data I can receive with JSON?
Am I receiving wrong my JSON data?

When I have "some" data it works fine, but when I have a lot of data I am not able to receive because it comes in parts and JSON do not recognizes as a single data.

Here is my JSON (JSONDictionaryExtensions):

```
NSData *receivedData = data;

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONData:data];
```

Here is data received with:

```
NSLog(@"Dados JSON:\n%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Good data sample:

> 2013-11-21 09:10:03.916 APP[38296:70b] Dados JSON:
>   {"nrAutenticacao1":"120360136","dtAutenticacao1":"20/12/12","nrOrdem1":"5","dsLivro1":"DIARIO","nrAutenticacao2":"080285899","dtAutenticacao2":"11/09/08","nrOrdem2":"4","dsLivro2":"DIARIO","nrAutenticacao3":"070212953","dtAutenticacao3":"30/07/07","nrOrdem3":"3","dsLivro3":"DIARIO","nrAutenticacao4":"070212970","dtAutenticacao4":"30/07/07","nrOrdem4":"2","dsLivro4":"DIARIO","nrAutenticacao5":"070212961","dtAutenticacao5":"30/07/07","nrOrdem5":"1","dsLivro5":"DIARIO","numLivros":5}
>
> 2013-11-21 09:10:03.917 APP[38296:70b] Recebidos 495 bytes de
>   dados.
>
> 2013-11-21 09:10:03.917 APP[38296:70b] DICTIONARY: {
>       dsLivro1 = DIARIO;
>       dsLivro2 = DIARIO;
>       dsLivro3 = DIARIO;
>       dsLivro4 = DIARIO;
>       dsLivro5 = DIARIO;
>       dtAutenticacao1 = "20/12/12";
>       dtAutenticacao2 = "11/09/08";
>       dtAutenticacao3 = "30/07/07";
>       dtAutenticacao4 = "30/07/07";
>       dtAutenticacao5 = "30/07/07";
>       nrAutenticacao1 = 120360136;
>       nrAutenticacao2 = 080285899;
>       nrAutenticacao3 = 070212953;
>       nrAutenticacao4 = 070212970;
>       nrAutenticacao5 = 070212961;
>       nrOrdem1 = 5;
>       nrOrdem2 = 4;
>       nrOrdem3 = 3;
>       nrOrdem4 = 2;
>       nrOrdem5 = 1;
>       numLivros = 5; }

Bad data sample:

> 2013-11-21 09:00:22.272 APP[38296:70b] Dados JSON:
>   {"nrAutenticacao1":"980367425","dtAutenticacao1":"25/08/98","nrOrdem1":"7","dsLivro1":"ATA
>   DE REUNIAO DE
>   DIRETORIA","nrAutenticacao2":"080363784","dtAutenticacao2":"18/12/08","nrOrdem2":"9","dsLivro2":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao3":"070179557","dtAutenticacao3":"22/06/07","nrOrdem3":"8","dsLivro3":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao4":"060260726","dtAutenticacao4":"05/10/06","nrOrdem4":"7","dsLivro4":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao5":"050206966","dtAutenticacao5":"23/08/05","nrOrdem5":"6","dsLivro5":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao6":"040043258","dtAutenticacao6":"11/03/04","nrOrdem6":"5","dsLivro6":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao7":"030152879","dtAutenticacao7":"16/10/03","nrOrdem7":"4","dsLivro7":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao8":"030152860","dtAutenticacao8":"16/10/03","nrOrdem8":"3","dsLivro8":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao9":"030152852","dtAutenticacao9":"16/10/03","nrOrdem9":"2","dsLivro9":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao10":"030152844","dtAutenticacao10":"16/10/03","nrOrdem10":"1","dsLivro10":"BALANCO","nrAutenticacao11":"990032957","dtAutenticacao11":"30/03/99","nrOrdem11":"3","dsLivro11":"CAIXA
>   PAGAMENTO","nrAutenticacao12":"990032965","dtAutenticacao12":"30/03/99","nrOrdem12":"2","dsLivro12":"CAIXA
>   PAGAMENTO","nrAutenticacao13":"980306
>
> ... (LOT OF DATA) ...
>
> 2013-11-21 09:00:22.585 APP[38296:70b] Dados JSON:
>   /06/98","nrOrdem419":"1","dsLivro419":"DIARIO AUXILIAR
>   ESTOQUE","numLivros":419}
>
> 2013-11-21 09:00:22.585 APP[38296:70b] Recebidos 81 bytes de dados.
>
> 2013-11-21 09:00:22.586 APP[38296:70b]
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x9d610a0
>   {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.}
>
> 2013-11-21 09:00:22.587 APP[38296:70b] DICTIONARY: (null)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold

Comment: Exactly what size is "lot of data"? Perhaps that is a new technical unit of measure? Where is the code?

Comment: In general you're limited only by the size of available heap.  But your scenario is quite common when you attempt to do the JSON deserialization in `didReceiveData:` when only part of the data's been received.

Comment: @Aishvarya... it's not duplicated. There's no connection between this post and that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not connected to JSON. Your problem is caused by the fact that data comes in separate chunks and you are trying to parse each chunk as a single JSON object.

You have to join the data chunks into one `NSData` object (`-[NSMutableData appendData:]`) and *then* use a JSON parser to parse them.

Comment: Thanx @Sulthan I was not able to append NSData/NSMutableData. Than I was trying to convert do NSString to append. But I solved appending NSMutableData.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this JSON from a website, copy the url into http://jsonlint.com to validate it.

Then try using NSJSONSerialization instead of JSONDictionaryExtensions.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];
```

If that works, then the problem lies in JSONDictionaryExtensions, so you would contact the developer on github that supplied it.