# HTTP ERROR 500 with json_decode when using large files

Tags: javascript, php, json, decode

I am decoding JSON files using the following:

```
$filename = 'file.json';
$json = file_get_contents($filename);
$data = json_decode ($json,true);
```

This works perfectly fine with files that are not large. It also works perfectly fine in XAMMP json_decode.

Small files work fine, but as soon as they get larger (few MB+), the HTTP 500 error kicks in.

$filename loads fine and completely in PHP, so that is not the issue.

Anyone any idea if this is an limitation of JSON handling large files or a server setting (put memory and time limits already to -1 and 0 in PHP).

Thanks!

Comment: what does the PHP error log say?

Comment: If you already amended memory limits I would guess you have chnaged the WRONG `php.ini` file. There are 2 one in the `apache\bin\` folder (affects PHP under apache) and one in the `php` folder (affects PHP CLI mode only).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on how much JSON can hold?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold)

Comment: There is also a time limit in PHP, try to call `set_time_limit(0)` before your `json_decode`.

Comment: The JSON was created by another site, filesize should not be the issue (max 22MB). It fails even with a 9MB file. So not a duplicate question.

Comment: I cannot find the 'other' php.ini file...also no log file seems to be created.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that would most likely cause this is PHP is running out of memory.

Check your **php.ini** under the **memory_limit** setting and increase it.

Also you will need to check your **max_execution_time** to make sure that it is not timing out.

One last thing before your json_encode statement: **set_time_limit(0);**

Also I would suggest using a package such as [JMS/Serializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer)

Comment: memory_limit is set at 128MB

Comment: max_execution_time is set at 200 (I get the error immideately though)

Comment: Do you can any errors or warnings in your error log?

Comment: Also check that your editing the correct php.ini...phpinfo() will tell you the location of the php.ini file being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Increasing server memory to 1GB solved it.