# i don't understand what's wrong with this JSON

Tags: json

JSON is located at:

> http://www.medialweb.it/corsi_ok.json

When I use the online tool:

> https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I get the following error messages:

```
Error:Invalid media type, expecting application/json.[Code 28,Structure 0] 
Error:Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.[Code 29, Structure 0]
```

Comment: Please remove the Link and add the JSON to this post

Comment: the JSON it's too big. if i try to paste it here the website stop working.

Comment: I agree @MatteoVilla, if I go to the link you pasted and I run JSON.parse(document.querySelector('pre').innerText) in the console, it gets parsed properly without errors

Comment: @MatteoVilla are you posting the URL in the jsonformatter tool to validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming:** You are pasting the "url" in the jsonformatter to validate the json.

Your JSON is structurally valid.

The errors shown are related to the missing metadata about content that your service should expose. Typically the client that would consume any resources you may expose over the network might/would like to know (among other things):

1. What *type* of content is being returned
2. What is the *charset* / character encoding I should use to make sense of the payload. Most of the clients default to UTF-8, so in that case, this error is more of a warning, but better to explicitly mention it.

The client would look for this information in the `Content-type` response header.

The server/service exposing that JSON, is not setting the `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` in the response header, thus the tool raises the error.

**Edit (Bonus tip):** If you have any confusion about the content header for the json, would definitely recommend reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/1695393)

Comment: I set my header to "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" and am still getting this same error message with this tool.

Comment: You need to use all caps: UTF-8, it's case-sensitive apparently.

Answer (score 3):

thanks @dubes

what worked for me, after doing everything!
change this:

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

to:

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

(caps)!

Answer (score 0):

use single line code in your php api file

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

Answer (score -1):

I thing the JSON data exceeds the maximum number of characters so, the error showing, if you partially valid the json file , the error will not show.

Comment: JSON does not have a limit of maximum characters. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1262376/1695393). The JSON is valid. The tool for validation may have limits on characters it can validate successfully, though I do not see any mention of the limit in the error message nor in the tool. If you have any reference to the limits enforced by the tool, please add them to your answer.