# Jetty charset utf-8 vs charset UTF-8

Tags: java, json, spring, utf-8, jetty

I am using a Spring-Web application using jetty:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Assume this http endpoint:

```java
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/example", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public ExampleResponse example() {
      return new ExampleResponse();
  }

  public static class ExampleResponse {
      private String dummy = "example";

      public String getDummy() {
          return dummy;
      }
  }
}
```

and curl against the Endpoint and inspect the header `curl -v localhost:8080/example`:

```
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /example HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2019 13:52:10 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

**Notice** the `charset=**utf-8**` in the response header, but I am setting the header via the annotation `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` to the value `application/json;charset=UTF-8`. So Jetty (using tomcat everything works fine) lowercases the charset in the response header.

Why is that a problem? Some people working against my endpoints and validate this with a JSON Valiadtor (like: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

This validator expects the charset in UPPERCASE. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48466826/3046582). So what can I do about this?

**Update:**

like @Kayaman says `System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.STRICT", "true");` bevor the Spring-Application run wil fix this.

I also found a workaround:    `MimeTypes.CACHE.remove("application/json;charset=utf-8");` will solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then that validator is broken. The [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) mandates case insensitivity.

> Note that both character set names and language tags are restricted to
> the US-ASCII character set, and are matched case-insensitively (see
> [RFC2978], Section 2.3 and [RFC5646], Section 2.1.1).

And the [W3 Org's example](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index) uses `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` as a "typical" header.

But if the question is, why does Jetty lowercase it? Well, I decided to skulk around in the sources, and found where the [charset is sanitized](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/71641716746bbec79b9fd895002182477eeeb183/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Response.java#L872).

And from there, going to [HttpGenerator](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpGenerator.java) we find

> If the system property "org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.STRICT"
> is set to true, then the generator will strictly pass on the exact
> strings received from methods and header fields.  Otherwise a fast
> case insensitive string lookup is used that may alter the case and
> white space of some methods/headers

Comment: I totally agree with you but, nevertheless why does jetty overwrite media type, when I explicit define it?

Comment: Well, it could be as simple as Jetty doing `.toLowerCase()` somewhere. You could take a look at [Jetty's source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project) to see where it's handling the response headers, if you're so inclined. But Jetty is working perfectly validly, so you should be more interested in the parties that require `UTF8` to be in uppercase.

Comment: @user3046582 fixed it for ya.

Comment: Jetty 9.4 follows the recommendations at [RFC7231 HTTP/1.1 Semantics and Content - Section 3.1.1.1 for Media Types](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1) - also note, `org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.STRICT` is deprecated, and moved to the `HttpCompliance` settings now (and in the future).