# What is the max size for script type text/json

Tags: javascript, html, json, typescript, size

I am trying to load `JSON` string in a `script tag` with `type` `text/json`.
Which will be read from `javascript` using `script tag` `Id` and parsed to `JavaScript Object`.

In some cases, where the data size is very large, a portion of data is only loading. Current length of the string in the script is **`10001`**.

Is there a limitation for the size script tag can hold?
Is there a way I can load whole data in the script tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on how much JSON can hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON doesn't have any limitations on size of data that can be stored. You can populate it as and when you need to.

[Refer this StackOverflow article for more detials.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold)

Answer (score 0):

Theres no max size for json, but the server could limit the JSON length on request