# What is the maximum size of a JSON object that can be retrieved through AJAX and processed with JS

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm generating plots with help of the JS library [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/). The data that is being used for plotting is retrieved by AJAX. In one particular case, around ~450MB is being retrieved through AJAX, to be used to generate those plots. The browser however, 'crashes'. It's not a timeout from the server because it's still running and it shows no errors in its logs (it's served by the django framework).

My question is, is 450MB of data too much to be loaded through AJAX? Or is this a Javascript problem? Is the processing of the data with this plotly library too much for the browser?

The computer that is making this request has 16GB or RAM of which 15.8 is available. It's using Chrome as the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on how much JSON can hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold)

Comment: @hindmost thank you. There's a subtle difference though. It answers one question but 2 others remain. Is this a Javascript issue or is the browser capacity, concerning rendering, limited?

Comment: Those questions are most likely off-topic to SO as "unreproducible"

Comment: What do mean by crashes ? It maybe takes years to evaluate data ?

Comment: I've recently struggled with a big JSON file (about 15000 records) and some AJAX calls. My conclusion was that my server (PHP) was limiting the JSON file in the AJAX calls. There are several settings that can contribute to that (php.ini or htaccess): "max_input_vars" -> defaults to 1000 , "post_max_size" -> defaults to 24M, though I'm not sure, "max_execution_time" -> defaults to 30

Comment: @H.Figueiredo that's irrelevant. My server isn't limiting anything. 450MB of data is a lot more than 15000 records.

Comment: @Shim-Sao it takes approximately 5 minutes to retrieve the data. I've just tried loading this on a different computer (Linux in a virtual box with Chromium) and it worked. I suppose it's either a hardware limitation or OS-relevant?

Comment: Sure, but if you recieve the data by post, the "post_max_size" could be the cause. But if that's not the case, what do you mean by crashes? Freezes?
Anyway, 450MB is a bit, considering your client will have to download that value each time (except for cached values). Your server Bandwith might also suffer .

Comment: @H.Figueiredo it's not a server issue since I cannot reproduce the same error on a virtual box with linux on it.

Comment: 5 minutes = 300 seconds => 450MB/300sec = 1.5MB/s does not seem to be a low value to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189194/discussion-between-albert-and-h-figueiredo).

Comment: Try to split your json and found the limit.