# What is the maximum length of a JSON response message?

Tags: json, limit, hangouts-api

I am using python to generate custom payload responses for a Hangouts ChatBot.

This works great but I have found some instances where the number of records I get returned from my BQ results and then add to my card responses as both text and buttons seem to be too large.

If I return 10-20 records it works as expected.  Both text and action buttons are displayed in the chatbot.  If the number of records goes above this it seems to just disregard/drop the message somewhere without an error or other indication.

Looking at the logs the call is repeated 3 times before stopping.  No error is ever thrown.
As this works with fewer records (and with several other questions with varying length data, but none with as much as this response), I am assuming that I am exceeding some message length limit.

Does anybody know if there is a limit and what it is?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a limit on how much JSON can hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold)

Comment: I don't think this is the reason for your problem, but keep in mind that the usage of  Hangouts API is subject to quotas. You can find them in your [gcp console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/quotas).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Unfortunately, I don't think it is a quota or Beta thing as if I send less records back to the API/Hangout it works as expected but when I sent just a couple more records it just hangs with no response.  It retries 3 times and then stops.